# Xcode update Simulators to newest build

Tags: xcode, ios8.3

I just finished downloading Xcode 6.3 and saw that the iOS 8.3 Simulators are running with the 12F69 Build. The current ist 12F70... I can't find any way to update them to the latest build.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may help you. The location of dmg files in apple.com is:

http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_1-8.1.1.1434581536.dmg

http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_2-8.2.1.1434581536.dmg

http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_3-8.3.1.1434581536.dmg

http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK8_4-8.4.1.1435785476.dmg